# Having problems with eclipse

Tags: android

i know that this question have been answered before but none have answered it the way i want.... Or perhaps the way i will understand.

I have installed eclipse and all the necessary tools for android development - including the support libraries.  But i have not been able to create any working project... Whenever i create a new project,  it always displays this error "error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme. AppCompat.Light"

One solution was to add the support library through the project's properties menu but whenever i click the "Add" button,  I see no library in the options - infact the input area looks somehow disabled.

Please am a kid just starting to learn programming,  i will be happy for a detailed solution... Thanks

Comment: Go for Android Studio, Eclipse is no longer supported for Android development.

Comment: Alright thanks... bt is there no other way of using eclipse because my system is really slow for android studio - or must i use only android studio?

Comment: You can use ONLY android studio. Its enough:)

Comment: Maybe there is (did not try since a long time), but you will most likely just waste your time fighting problems.

Comment: But with Android studio,  i dont need to download any more tools right?

Answer (score 0):

You should switch to Android Studio. Because it is not supported for Android Development anymore. You said you have a slow system. I suggest you test your applications on a real device instead of an emulator.